# Flutter: upload image using binary body

Tags: dart, flutter, upload, binary

I want to upload a file using binary body like in the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

So far I just have:

```
      save() async {
         http.put(url,headers:headers, body: );
```

Comment: What does it do now? And what's the issue?

Comment: No issue, the only problem is that I don 't know how to specify that I want to insert a binary body.

Answer (score 12):

The `body` parameter of the `put` method accepts a `List<int>` that will be used as a list of bytes

From the `http` API reference: https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/put.html

> body sets the body of the request. It can be a String, a List or
>   a Map. If it's a String, it's encoded using encoding
>   and used as the body of the request. The content-type of the request
>   will default to "text/plain".
>
> If body is a List, it's used as a list of bytes for the body of the
>   request.
>
> If body is a Map, it's encoded as form fields using encoding. The
>   content-type of the request will be set to
>   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; this cannot be overridden.

Examples to send a file:

```
main() async {
  await put(url, body: File('the_file').readAsBytesSync());
}
```

Comment: Worked for me. I was uploading the file on AWS3 bucket and not able to send file over the server but this solution helped me lot. 
Thanks @Xavier.

Comment: Worked well :+1

Comment: You are a life saver. I have been on this for about 3 days now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using http.Request, the you can use the code below:

```
var request = http.Request('PUT', Uri.parse(url));

request.bodyBytes = file.readAsBytesSync(); // set file bytes to request.bodyBytes  

http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

var responseJson;

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  responseJson = 'Upload success';
} else {
  responseJson = 'Upload failed.';
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use this for upload Image

```
Future uploadImage(File imageFile)async{
  var stream= new http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(imageFile.openRead()));
  var length= await imageFile.length();
  var uri = Uri.parse("Image upload url");
  var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
  var filename = "Your image name";
  var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile("image", stream, length, filename: basename(filename));
  request.files.add(multipartFile);
  var response = await request.send();
  if(response.statusCode==200){
    print("Image Uploaded");
  }else{
    print("Upload Failed");
 }
}
```

Comment: What is DelegatingStream?